# select2 3.5.0 - jumps on first opening in IE

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'm using select2.js dynamically bound with data.

When I'm using it in IE it's show's a part of it in the bottom of the screen and disappears and the main scrollbar is appearing for a second and disappears.

After first time that this happens, it's not appears again, until next page reload.

How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery 2.11

Comment: As far I can see it's working. Can you please show your problem in a sample fiddle or provide the code.

Comment: How can I rip that piece of code and build jsfiddle? It's very complex to simulate it.

Comment: At least can you show the code where you are building the dropdown/select list, also any change function that you have used to select any item in that list

Comment: You can see here the guy has the same issue, but no one solved it.
https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1515

Comment: Unable to get this in IE10.

Comment: Do you familiar with issue at all?

Comment: If you can help in reproducing the issue, by adding in any fiddle then probably anyone can help you out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68166/discussion-between-user3263194-and-iamstalker).